# RAILS 4.1.4: My class in the lib folder loads as a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've written a tiny game in the form of a Class.  I've placed that file in the lib folder and I've set the appropriate loader in config/application.rb .  But when I try to call Game.new in my controller it says `undefined method 'new' for Game:Module`.  I want to be very clear **THIS IS NOT A MODULE**.  Why the heck is it treating my class as a module?  How can I fix it?

```
class Game
  def initialize
  end
end
```

See... this is a class with the `.new` method.  It loads fine in IRB, but not in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  It turns out I had named the class the same name as my rails project name.  So it would only accept a module for that name.  I renamed the class and file and now I'm good to go.